# Reformat output values in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have list of projects. In every project I calculate some values for every user that are part of project. So on exit i get something like this -

```
Project1
user1 - value1
user2 - value2

Project2
user1 - value3
user3 - value4

...

Project10
user8 - value5
user9 - value6
```

I want to transform it in next form :

```
User1
Project1 - value1
Project2 - value3

User2
Project1 - value2

...

User9
Project10 - value6
```

I need some idea or example how to implement it.

For me it seems like i need create some collection where key can be un-unique (key - it can be User name and values - value for user). So i can go through list of projects, add keyValue pair to output list. Or there is better approach?

Comment: use group-by on users... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq

Comment: @A.T. i can use groub-by on users in case i have such simple logic, where i can easily get access to users. But it isn't my case. In loop through project list I call API method to get that users... So for me this isn't answer

Comment: it's not an answer it's a comment, anyway you should draft such complexity in questions so we can better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Lookup<Tkey,TValue>` which allows duplicate keys since the value is always an `IEnumerable<TValue>`, so even an non-available key returns [`Enumerable<TValue>.Empty()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042.aspx).

```
var userLookup = projectList.ToLookup(p => p.User);
```

Now you can lookup a specific user in this way:

```
IEnumerable<Project> userProjects = userLookup["User1"]; // presuming it's a string
```

Another option is to use `GroupBy`:

```
var userGroups = projectList
    .GroupBy(p => p.User)
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key);


foreach(var grp in userGroups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(grp.Key); // user
    foreach(Project p in grp)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", p.Name, p.Value);
}
```